# FullCalendar - inline scrollable calendar

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm hardly editing Easy!Appoinments to adapt it to our needs.
I'm developing a page that lists a biweekly providers' calendar.

FullCalendar allows to create a biweekly calendar with this option:

```
views: {
   agendaBiWeek: {
       type: 'basic',
       duration: { weeks: 2 },
       buttonText: '14 giorni'
   }
},
```

but the 2 weeks are split into 2 rows.

I, instead, would like to show 14 days in only **one scrollable row**.

**This is my actual situation:**
[image: All providers' calendar, 2 rows]

[image: Calendar with events]

But I'd like to have this result:
[image]

I'm obtain this result by manipute DOM objects through JS, but when refreshed, it all mess up. Fullcalendar adds new events expecting to find 2 rows.

The only easy way to make it work is to alter CSS in order to show the 2 DIV inline, but I don't know how to do it because there are too many elements.

Can you help me?

I create the calendar with this options:

```
$('#custom-calendar-' + provider.id).fullCalendar({
                defaultView: 'agendaBiWeek',
                height: BackendCalendarDefaultView._getCalendarHeight,
                contentHeight: 100,
                editable: true,
                firstDay: 1,
                snapDuration: '00:30:00',
                timeFormat: timeFormat,
                slotLabelFormat: slotTimeFormat,
                columnHeader: false,
                header: {
                    left: null,
                    center: null,
                    right: null
                },
                // visibleRange: {
                //     start: '2020-03-22',
                //     end: '2020-03-25'
                // },
                views: {
                    agendaBiWeek: {
                        type: 'basic',
                        duration: { weeks: 2 },
                        buttonText: '14 giorni'
                    }
                },
                // Selectable
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                select:              

                                           .

                                           .

                                           .

                                           .
```

This is an example of generated calendar:

```
<div id="custom-calendar-105" class="custom-calendar fc fc-unthemed fc-ltr" style="">
    <div class="fc-view-container" style="">
        <div class="fc-view fc-agendaBiWeek-view fc-basic-view" style="">
            <table class="">
                <tbody class="fc-body">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="fc-widget-header-custom">Provider14</th>
                        <td class="fc-widget-content">
                            <div class="fc-scroller fc-day-grid-container" style="overflow: hidden; height: 98.4px;">
                                <div class="fc-day-grid fc-unselectable">
                                    <div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content" style="">
                                        <div class="fc-bg">
                                            <table class="">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr class="giorno">
                                                        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-past" data-date="2020-01-20"></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-past" data-date="2020-01-21"></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-past" data-date="2020-01-22"></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-today " data-date="2020-01-23"></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2020-01-24"></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2020-01-25"></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-future" data-date="2020-01-26"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="fc-content-skeleton">
                                            <table class="eventiGiorno">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="fc-day-top fc-mon fc-past" data-date="2020-01-20"><span class="fc-day-number">20</span></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day-top fc-tue fc-past" data-date="2020-01-21"><span class="fc-day-number">21</span></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day-top fc-wed fc-past" data-date="2020-01-22"><span class="fc-day-number">22</span></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day-top fc-thu fc-today " data-date="2020-01-23"><span class="fc-day-number">23</span></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day-top fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2020-01-24"><span class="fc-day-number">24</span></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day-top fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2020-01-25"><span class="fc-day-number">25</span></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day-top fc-sun fc-future" data-date="2020-01-26"><span class="fc-day-number">26</span></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-event-container"><a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable">
                                                                <div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">14:30</span> <span class="fc-title">MONTES</span></div>
                                                            </a></td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content" style="">
                                        <div class="fc-bg">
                                            <table class="">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2020-01-27"></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2020-01-28"></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2020-01-29"></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2020-01-30"></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2020-01-31"></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2020-02-01"></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-future" data-date="2020-02-02"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="fc-content-skeleton">
                                            <table>
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="fc-day-top fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2020-01-27"><span class="fc-day-number">27</span></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day-top fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2020-01-28"><span class="fc-day-number">28</span></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day-top fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2020-01-29"><span class="fc-day-number">29</span></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day-top fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2020-01-30"><span class="fc-day-number">30</span></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day-top fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2020-01-31"><span class="fc-day-number">31</span></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day-top fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2020-02-01"><span class="fc-day-number">1</span></td>
                                                        <td class="fc-day-top fc-sun fc-future" data-date="2020-02-02"><span class="fc-day-number">2</span></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you wanted to fundamentally change the layout in this way, you'd probably need a completely custom view - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js. This is because, as you've noticed, you'd also need to change the event rendering algorithm so that it overlays the elements in the correct place where it's expecting the days to be. But, that is a lot of work, and I probably wouldn't do it because...

Comment: ...actually you can achieve that kind of layout much more easily by using the Timeline view: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-view - it's a premium add-on which most organisations will need to buy a license for (see https://fullcalendar.io/license/premium) ...but then again you mentioned this "easy appointments", I don't if that is some kind of commercial version of fullCalendar already? So perhaps cost is not going to be a big issue for you.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Easy! Appointments is a open source booking project that included fullcalendar library (basic version). However I menaged to do what I wanted (using CSS). In the next days I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MY SOLUTION:**

I simply modified the css like this:

```
#calendar-page .custom-calendar .fc-scroller{
    overflow-x: scroll !important;
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
    height: auto !important
}

#calendar-page .custom-calendar .fc-scroller > .fc-day-grid {
    width: 200%
}

#calendar-page .custom-calendar .fc-basic-view .fc-body .fc-row {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%
}

#calendar-page .custom-calendar .fc-row td {
    width: 90px;
}

#calendar-page .fc th.fc-widget-header-custom {
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #calendar-page .fc th.fc-widget-header-custom {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #calendar-page .fc th.fc-widget-header-custom + td {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        border: none
    }

    #calendar-page .custom-calendar .fc-row:first-of-type {
        border-left: 1px solid #ddd
    }
}
```